how to make Bun keyword available in sveltekit
I'm using bun to run sveltekit app, and trying to write file with Bun API
    Bun.write(pathname, new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer()))

And it seems sveltekit won't regonize Bun variable. So how can we remove the error ?
so that's my question, I have no more word to describe the question. But stack overflow is saying my post is mainly a picture, need more words so I'm just wriing a bunch of words to post this question.


Add @types/bun to your project:
bun add -D @types/bun
